# How to use next date column value to calculate delta for current column

Tags: sql, mysqli

I have a temp table

```
BusinessDate    SSQ_CompScore
2011-01-05 00:00:00.000 41
2011-01-06 00:00:00.000 6
2011-01-07 00:00:00.000 1
2011-01-10 00:00:00.000 8
2011-01-11 00:00:00.000 48
2011-01-12 00:00:00.000 50
2011-01-13 00:00:00.000 59
```

I need to calculate delta for each current date.
I have prepared a solution but it doesn't work where date as not consecutive.
Can you please help?

```
select t1.businessdate, t1.ssq_compscore, (t2.ssq_compscore - t1.ssq_compscore) as delta
from #temp t1
left join #temp t2 on  t1.businessdate = DATEADD(dd,1,t2.businessdate)
where t1.businessdate >='20180814'
```

Result set should be as

```
BusinessDate            SSQ_CompScore Delta
2011-01-05 00:00:00.000   41           NULL
2011-01-06 00:00:00.000   6            35 
2011-01-07 00:00:00.000   1            5
2011-01-10 00:00:00.000   8            7
2011-01-11 00:00:00.000   48          40 
2011-01-12 00:00:00.000   50           2
2011-01-13 00:00:00.000   59           9
```

Comment: Specify the expected result as well!

Comment: @gagandawar . . . Your code does not look like MySQL code (the table names that start with `#` are suspicious.  Are you sure you are using MySQL?

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if this is the most efficient way but it works as far as I see

```
SELECT businessdate, SSQ_CompScore , 
       SSQ_CompScore - (SELECT SSQ_CompScore 
                        FROM temp 
                        WHERE businessdate < t1.businessdate
                        ORDER BY businessdate DESC
                        LIMIT 1) as delta
FROM temp t1
ORDER BY businessdate ASC
```